# Oracle not available error with Oracle XE 11.2.0-1.0

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer

I have downloaded Oracle XE 11.2.0-1.0 and installed it on a CentOS 6.3 virtual machine with 1.5GB memory and 3GB of swap.

SYS and SYSTEM set to have password 123456. I have set `ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/` and `ORACLE_SID=XE`.

I can connect to this database with SQL Developer with the SYSTEM user. But when I want to connect with `sqlplus` it says:

```
ERROR.
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

`ps -fe | grep pmon` shows this:

```
oracle    1164    1    0    11:26    ?    00:00:00    xe_pmon_XE
```

I have logged in as root user and I just type `sqlplus` with no arguments then it asks for user name and password.

Can anyone help?

Comment: That usually means you haven't started Oracle (but the listener is running).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can create tables, ... in the database using sql developer.

Comment: is there a pmon process running? what is the output of `ps -fe|grep pmon`? I am not familiar with sqldeveloper. what connection data do you use to connect to the system?

Comment: i misread your post. how do you connect with sqlplus?

Comment: Then your connection using SQL*Plus is wrong. Please show us the connection details you use in SQL Developer **and** SQL*Plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed the trailing `/` from `ORACLE_HOME` and it solved my problem.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me!